# Cannot find module 'http-simple-proxy' - although everything is set correctly

Tags: node.js, npm, module

I installed http-simple-proxy **globally**. I even have it as command in the shell. Then - I created a small JS file with the content from the README (the first section, **Installation and basic usage**), but when I run it with `node {name-of-JS-file}` - and it failed with:

```
$ node {name-of-JS-file} 
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'http-simple-proxy'
Require stack:
- {name-of-JS-file}
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> ({name-of-JS-file:3:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '{name-of-JS-file' ]
}
```

I have setup the necessary stuff correctly:

```
$ node -v
v14.16.0

$ npm -v
7.8.0

$ echo $NODE_PATH
/home/petar/.npm-packages

$ ls -la $NODE_PATH
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 petar users 4096 Oct 26 15:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 62 petar users 4096 Apr 21 21:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 petar users 4096 Apr 21 20:56 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 petar users 4096 Oct 19  2020 etc
drwxr-xr-x  3 petar users 4096 Oct 15  2020 lib
drwxr-xr-x  3 petar users 4096 Oct 26 15:19 share

$ which http-simple-proxy 
/home/petar/.npm-packages/bin/http-simple-proxy

$ http-simple-proxy 
usage: http-simple-proxy [options] 

Starts a http-simple-proxy server using the specified command-line options

options:
  --version
  --config CONFIGFILE     Configuration file (YAML or JSON)
  --configloader JS-FILE  Provide js file as config loader
  --configloader-test     Test config configloader by printing out its output
  --watch                 Watch config for changes and automatically reload with zero downtime
  --silent                Silence the log output
  --user   USER           User to drop privileges to once server socket is bound
  --group  GROUP          Group to drop privileges to once server socket is bound
  --show-rules            Show all rules upon every config load
  -h, --help              You're staring at it
See https://github.com/gusnips/http-simple-proxy for further info
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

> I installed http-simple-proxy globally.

Globally installed packages are not available for import/require from Node.js programs. You need to install it locally, or at least in the path to your project. Note that the README say to `npm install --save http-simple-proxy` and does not say to install it globally. Install it globally to get the executable available to your shell, but not to use in a Node.js program itself.